# Probability of discovering a defect with a set sampling rate

Tags: probability, sampling

I'm not sure how to tackle this question.

The probability of a process producing a defective part is 1 in 100.

1 product is sampled every 2000 parts.

Total parts produced are 40,000.

What is the probability that the 1 part sampled is defective?

Comment: The way the question is stated it sounds like 20 parts are sampled. This question should have the self study tag.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean *at least* one out of the 20 or perhaps *exactly* one of the 20?  If the first, just use 1 - P(zero bad), if the second, use a binomial P(good)^19 * P(bad)^1 * 20choose1